# vertical layout not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I just started working with Android and I'm following a video guide.
In the video, whenever he adds a `TextView` it adds in vertical way...
but for me it adds each `TextView` one on top of the other.. no kind of order.
This is my initial code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.thebasics.MainActivity" >

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="wassup" />
  <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I added `android:orientation="vertical"` but it didn't work. I don't get any error.. it simply does nothing. I still get that it puts the objects one on another.

What shall I do to solve this? I want both `TextViews` in vertical order.
I couldn't find the answer elsewhere and the video guide got it by default so he doesn't explain what to do if it doesn't work.

Comment: Because you are using a RelativeLayout, not a LinearLayout! `android:orientation="vertical"` works only for LinearLayouts (and derivates).

Comment: thank you Der... he didn't talk about it in the guide so i didn't notice... i change it now and it's working!

Comment: Relative Layout initially sets every widget at the left top corner, you need to set its position manually. And orientation="vertical" is not required in relative layout

Comment: @user3794826: no need to use `LinearLayout` you can achieve same using `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK True, but you have to set an id for each "previous" View, so that the next one can be put below it, by referring that id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it adds each textView one on top of the other.. no any kind of order

There is actually an order. `RelativeLayout` puts `Views`in the top-left by default so it's using it's default "order", if you will. You would need to use the different layout properties of `RelativeLayout` to position them otherwise.

> i added android:orientation="vertical"

`RelativeLayout` doesn't have an `orientation` property so this will have no effect.

> what shall i do to solve this?

You could use `android:layout_below="@id/idOfAboveTV"` but that could be cumbersome unless you need/want `RelativeLayout` for some other reason.

You can change it to a `LinearLayout` and since LL has a default `orientation` of `horizontal`, just add `android:orientation="vertical"` and your `Views` will be layed out in a vertical fashion.

**Note:** if you use `LinearLayout` then you will want to remove some of the `View` params that are `RelativeLayout`-specific such as `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`

**Links to helpful documentation**

[RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

[Relative Layout Layout Params](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

[LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html)

[LinearLayout Layout Params](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `LinearLayout` as root element, not `RelativeLayout`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.thebasics.MainActivity" >
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:orientation="vertical"` is for `LinearLayouts`, and you are using a `RelativeLayout`.

If you want your textviews one above the other, just replace your Relatives by Linear and set the orientation to vertical as you did:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.thebasics.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="wassup" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</LinearLayout>
```